# Error on Reconcile - Inconsistent Network State

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, versioning, arcfm, reconcile

I am encountering an error that I am not sure how to address when I reconcile an edit session.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.1, ArcFM 10.2.1a, connected to a SQL 2012 database via a direct connection using operating system authentication on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

I am receiving the error while attempting to reconcile a session containing a large number of edits removing loops from an electrical network.

Here is the error I receive:
[image]

I think I have a good understanding of what the error is describing - I just can't figure out how to address it.

My first thought was to add the Network Junctions to the map and look for junction 85752 and 90717 but when I add the junctions it comes in from DEFAULT, not the version that I'm trying to reconcile and those junctions don't exist in default (or at least I can't find them in the table).  So that seems to be a dead end.

I've also tried running the "Repair Connectivity" and "Verify Connectivity" tools from the Geometric Network Editing toolbar (both were run on the entire network - NOT the current extent) in hopes that those would deal with the inconsistency and then it would reconcile.  Both tools ran without incident and neither had any impact on the result.

My fundamental question is: **Is there anything I can do about this or do I just need to delete the version and start over?**

--EDIT--

I found an ESRI help article that addresses this issue (I've been through the ESRI help article on this error (http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21187) it seems like my only option if the tools don't run right is to delete the version and start over.  Which isn't great news but I thought I'd post it here in case someone was curious.